# How to print the complete json array using python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json array. And need to print only the id using python .How do i do it ?

This is my json array :

```
{
"messages":
  [
   {

   "id": "1531cf7d9e03e527",
   "threadId": "1531cf7d9e03e527"
   },

   {
   "id": "1531cdafbcb4a0e6",
   "threadId": "1531bfccfceb1ed7"
   }

 ],

 "nextPageToken": "01647645424797380808",

 "resultSizeEstimate": 103
}
```

*EDIT : *

I am actually writing a python code to get messages from the gmail API.
This program gives the message ids and thread ids of a gmail accounts' messages as a json format. I only need the message id and not the thread id.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
import json
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
    flags = None


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_server.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'

def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: 
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials
def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id='').execute()
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='').execute()
    messages = []
    if 'messages' in response:
      messages.extend(response['messages'])
      print(messages)

    result = loads(messages)
    ids = [message['id'] for message in result['messages']]
    print (ids)

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='',pageToken=page_token).execute()
      messages.extend(response['messages'])
     print(message['id'])

    print (message['snippet'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
dict_result = json.loads(your_json)
ids = [message['id'] for message in dict_result['messages']]
```

Comment: TypeError : expected string or buffer .. it gives me raw_decode() error @andrey

Comment: It seems you pass python list instead of JSON string(like you said in answer). 
If so, just skip part with json.loads and make list iterator on your list. `[message['id'] for message in your_parsed_json['messages']]` in your case

Answer (score 1):

```
messages=[]
store=[]
if 'messages' in response:
 messages.extend(response['messages'])
for i in range(len(messages)):
 //to store the id alone (Taking the id from the json array)
 store=messages[i]['id']  
 //retrieve messages of this id
 message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=store).execute()
 print(store)
```

Comment: Please add some description to the solution you propose.